# IIS "Error loading msvcr100.dll" from Microsoft.SqlServer.Types loader.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, iis, dll

After setting up an existing (and functioning) .net api application on a new machine, I encounter this error: `Error loading msvcr100.dll (ErrorCode: 5)`. That error is coming from `SqlServerTypes.Utilities.LoadNativeAssembly` which is a generated method from the Microsoft.SqlServer.Types [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.Types/). (You can take a look at [the generated code](http://sourcebrowser.io/Browse/jonwagner/Insight.Database/Insight.Tests/SqlServerTypes/Loader.cs)).

I know that error code 5 is a permissions error, but I can't find anything wrong with the permissions itself. If I comment out the `msvcr100.dll` line, the same error occurs trying to load `SqlServerSpatial110.dll`.

As many other posts have mentioned, this is normally an issue with Visual C++ Redistributable 2010, but I've reinstalled that multiple times now.

I suspect the issue is in my IIS settings, but I'm unable to figure out where that might be. Any help on this?

---

*Update: I was able to fix the issue by explicitly [adding `IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool`](https://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities) as a user with access to the project folder. But, no one else on the team has had to do this, so I still believe there is some setting in IIS I'm missing.